# passed data from a component shows undefined in another one

Tags: angular

I have two component and a service to transfer data here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
    public sharedData:any;
    constructor() { }
}
```

i injected service to both components ,here is my first service which sends data:

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient,private dataService:DataService)
{ }


this.http.post("backendURL",quote).subscribe(s=>{
    this.dataService.sharedData=s;
}
```

here is my second component that consumes the service:

```
     public modaldata:any;
     constructor(private dataServce:DataService) {  }
```

i just want to alert the data but it shows undefiend:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
       alert(this.dataServce.sharedData);
  }
```

any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i console.log data there,and i can see it@ShafiqulBariSadman

Comment: do you console data from second component where it showing undefined?

Comment: @ShafiqulBariSadman i alert it,which shows undefiend

Answer (score 1):

try to set data below way also you can use `behaviourSubject()` and `viewChild()`

- using service

1.DataService.ts

```
sharedData: any;

getData(){
    return this.sharedData;
}

setData(data){
    this.sharedData = data;
}
```

2.set data component.ts

```
this.http.post("backendURL",quote).subscribe(s=>{
    this.dataService.setData(s);
  }
```

3.get data to other component

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      const data = this.dataService.getData();
      console.log(data);
  }
```

- using `viewChild` here not need to use service you can directly access any methods and property from other component.

1.setdata YourComponent

```
   public shareData : any;
   ngOnInit(){
       this.http.post("backendURL",quote).subscribe(s=>{
         this.shareData = s;
       }
   }
```

2.get Data to other component

```
  @ViewChild(YourComponent) private getData: YourComponent;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      const data = this.getData.shareData;
      console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: now its showing [object][object] in my alert

Comment: can you check in `this.dataService.setData(s);` here what's value of s in log?

Comment: sure its,in my console i have: DataService {sharedData: 'e7ab0b2d-0726-45b1-9b77-e55a8335f052'}

Comment: it means, `this.dataService.getData();` here you get same data in log.

Comment: sorry ,i did not get you,am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: i mean to say you get same `{sharedData: 'e7ab0b2d-0726-45b1-9b77-e55a8335f052'}` this data in other components when u get data through `getData()` function.

Comment: {sharedData: 'e7ab0b2d-0726-45b1-9b77-e55a8335f052'} this is the data im sending,i consoled it to see what im sending,in the receiver component i have getData() like this const data = this.dataService.getData(); and data here is null,means its not getting the data

Comment: where is the viewchild by the way?what you have described in your answer

Comment: ya sure i 'll update in my ans.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this approach is that when you try to show the `sharedData` using the `alert`, the API call is not yet completed.

What is awesome in Angular (and not only, you can use it with multiple other libraries and frameworks) is RXJS. By leveraging the power of observables and subjects, you can get pass this racing condition issue.

Try to turn `sharedData` into a `BehaviorSubject` for example, and you can then do something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private sharedDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  public sharedData$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.sharedData$ = this.sharedDataSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public updateSharedData(data: any): void {
    this.sharedDataSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

When your data is available, you can update the shared data like this:

```
this.http.post("backendURL", quote).subscribe(data => {
  this.dataService.updateSharedData(data);
});
```

And to consume it, you only need to subscribe to that public observable:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.sharedData$.pipe(
    filter(data => !!data) // filter out the first null value
    // or replace the BehaviorSubject with Subject if you do not need a default value
  ).subscribe(data => {
    alert(this.dataServce.sharedData);
  });
}
```

There's a caveat though. For the observables that you create, you also need to manage the subscription in order not to create memory leaks. If you subscribe to this observable in your component, then you also need to unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed. Alternatively, you can use the `async` pipe in your template to render the data, and then you don't need to manually take care of the subscription.

In the consuming component (the one that does the subscribe) you need to store the subscription somewhere. There are multiple approaches to this, but I found the following to be somewhat simple:

```
private subscriptions = new Subscription();
```

All the calls to `subscribe` return such a `Subscription` object that you can use to unsubscribe when needed. In this case, the `ngOnInit` implementation becomes this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const sub = this.dataService.sharedData$.pipe(
    filter(data => !!data)
  ).subscribe(data => {
    alert(this.dataServce.sharedData);
  });
  this.subscriptions.add(sub);
}
```

And you also need a `ngOnDestroy` to unsubscribe:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: im getting null,has something to do with module.ts?even thought im passing hardcoded data!

Comment: You can use Subject instead of BehaviorSubject. Try `private sharedDataSubject = new Subject<any>();` inside of the `DataService`.

Comment: so weird but im getting null,the thing is in the console,seems the code in the receiver component is executing first,because in my console shows thats the first one shows null,how come?

Comment: Make sure to log inside the `subscribe` handler, not outside of it. It is possible that the receiver component instantiates first, that's why you need the asynchronicity of the observable in the first place, to get access to the data after it is available and usable.

Comment: by asyc you mean subscribe?

Comment: By async I mean the data you request from the API is not going to be available immediately, but after the request and also the result are transported back and forth via the network layer.

Comment: its very confusing ,i have subscribed to the data which is behaviurSubject but still the alert fires faster and shows null

Comment: Did you also applied the `filter` as in the code snippet I included in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `data.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class DataService {

private sharedData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

   constructor() { }

   setData(data: any) : void {
      this.sharedData.next(data);
   }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
     return this.sharedData.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Do this in the component that is passing the data

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient,private dataService:DataService)
{
    this.http.post("backendURL",quote)
      .subscribe(s => {
          this.dataService.setData(s);
         });
}
```

Do this on the component that is receiving the data:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataServce.getData().subscribe(data => {
     alert(data);
  });

}
```

Comment: im getting null,has something to do with module.ts?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the module.ts. I believe your backend is returning null, please verify if you are getting a valid value from the backend or not.

Comment: i hardcoded now,but i get null there

Comment: seems the component receiving is running earlier than the others and shows null,